# Python Multiprocessing doesn't behave as expected

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have the following code:
it should get some inputs and then process them and generate whatever i want.
the issue is that I debugged the processes by using file methods and I can see unexpected behavior which doesn't happen when I'm using multithreading.

```
#name = upperscript1

from multiprocessing import Process,Lock,Queue

def multiprocessing(*args , **kwargs):
    network = ['some array of network devices']

    queue = Queue()     # for multiprocessing
    lock = Lock()           # for multiprocessing

    ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
    ff.write('network@@@@\n')
    ff.close()
    
    _thread = []
    thread_count = 0
    for val in network:
        ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
        ff.write('aaa111\n')
        ff.close()
        _thread.append(Process(target = connect , args = [user , passw , auto_conf , val , IP_LIST , IP_EXIST , DELETE_LIST, VIP_IP] , kwargs = {'queue':queue , 'lock':lock}))         # for multiprocessing
        ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
        ff.write('aaa222\n')
        ff.close()
        #_thread.append(ThreadWithReturnValue(target = connect , args = [user , passw , auto_conf , val , IP_LIST , IP_EXIST , DELETE_LIST, VIP_IP]))        # for threading
        _thread[thread_count].start()
        ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
        ff.write('aaa666\n')
        ff.close()
        thread_count += 1
        
    returned_list = []
    for x in _thread:
        ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
        ff.write('aaa333\n')
        ff.close()
        x.join()
        #returned_list.append(x.join())                 # for threading
        
    while not queue.empty():                                # for multiprocessing
        returned_list.append(queue.get())       # for multiprocessing

    ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
    ff.write('aaa444\n')
    ff.close()
    return returned_list





# start all of the functions and connect to the devices
def connect(username , password , auto_conf , val , IP_LIST2 , IP_EXIST , DELETE_LIST , IP_VIP , queue = False , lock = None):
    ff = open(r'./logs.txt' , 'a')
    ff.write('aaa555\n')
    ff.close()
```

---

EDIT:

In another script I have the following function:

```
# name = upperscript2

import upperscript1

#calling the function:
def do(*args , **kwargs):
    upperscript.multiprocessing(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then in another new script I have the main call:

```
# name = Main Script

import upperscript2

upperscript2.do(x, y, z)
```

The issue is that the program behave unexpected, here is the output file generated:

```
network@@@@
aaa111
aaa222
aaa666
aaa333
network@@@@
aaa111
aaa222
aaa444
```

when I'm using multithreading, I get the following output which indeed behave as expected:

```
network@@@@
aaa111
aaa222
aaa555
aaa666
aaa333
aaa444
```

I couldn't find the problem and hope that any1 could help me fix it.

Thanks you very much

Comment: The very first line of your code is a SyntaxError! Please review the [ask] and especially the [mcve] page. Aside from providing code that actually runs, please ensure that the code is *readable* and *short* – there seems to be lots of unused and duplicate code (e.g. ``queue`` and repeated opening of the same file), and misleading naming conventions (e.g. storing processes in ``_threads``).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `multiprocessing(*args, **kwargs)` to a

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       #calling the function:
       multiprocessing(*args, **kwargs)
```

block.  Multiprocessing re-runs the script with some special arguments that keep it from executing the program like it does from the command line.  But in order to run `connect()` it's got to execute your whole script, so it's re-running the `multiprocessing()` function.

Comment: Is this behaviour also true when I call that function from another script which imports those functions into it?

Comment: Yes, when you import a module, it executes the entire file (unless it's already been imported).  So if you have a function call in that file then it will call it.  The way to keep this from happening in an import but still allow it to do things if called from the command line is to check that __name__ == '__main__'.